# Jquery code work in browser - but not device

Tags: jquery, html, iphone, responsive-design

I seem to have the same issue as this thread.

[Jquery code not working on mobile device but working in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284931/jquery-code-not-working-on-mobile-device-but-working-in-browser)

In my site http://dknytkom.dk/forside/ the menu bottom (which appear by media-query once the page width is less than 480px) will toogle the menu underneath the link.

On the browser this works fine - but not on my iphone.

The click seems to work but the div class="menu" don't toggle.

```
$menuknap.click(function(){

$('.menu').toggle(); $('a').css('color','red'); $emneoversigt.removeClass('listitem').addClass('displaynone'); });
```

I tried to use an on() method instead but it did not seem to attach properly.

Here is the html:

```
<ul>
            <li><a class="soege-knap mob-nav"></a></li>
            <li><a class="menu-knap mob-nav" ></a></li>
        </ul>

<div class="menu">
    <ul id="menu-list-portal" class="menu-list venstrefloat">
        <li><a href="<?=$grundsti;?>forside/?sekt=Stat">Stat</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?=$grundsti;?>forside/?sekt=Region">Region</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?=$grundsti;?>forside/?kat=35">KL</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?=$grundsti;?>forside/?sekt=Kommune">Kommune</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?=$grundsti;?>forside/?sekt=EU">EU</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?=$grundsti;?>debat.php">Debat</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?=$grundsti;?>forside/?baggrund=1">Baggrund</a></li>
    </ul>
        <div id="indexbtn" style="cursor:pointer" class="hoejrefloat"><a>&nbsp;Fagområder&nbsp;&#9662;</a></div>
        <div class="clearfloat"></div>
<div class="clearfloat"></div>
<div id="emneoversigt" class="displaynone">
        <ul><li><a class="counter padding5 background-colour7" href="<?=$grundsti;?>forside/?kat=<?=$kategori['id'];?>"></a></li>
                        </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the full script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$soeg = $('a.soege-knap');
$mobnav = $('a.mob-nav');
$soegelist = $('div#search-table') ;
$searchtable = $('#search-table') ;
$soegefelt = $('ul.menu-item-holder > li:last-child');
$menuknap = $('a.menu-knap');
$menu = $('div.menu')
$menulist = $('.menu li')
$emneoversigt = $('#emneoversigt')
$emneoversigtlistitem = $('#emneoversigt li')
$('.mob-nav').css('cursor','pointer');


$soeg.click(function(){


$soegelist.toggle();
$soegefelt.toggle();
$soeg.toggleClass("x")
                                                                        });
    $menuknap.click(function(){

$('.menu').toggle();
$('a').css('color','red');
$emneoversigt.removeClass('listitem').addClass('displaynone');
});

            $('#indexbtn').click(function(){    
                                    $emneoversigt.toggleClass('listitem');

                            });
```

Comment: Der er da ingen class="menu-knap" - also error on `$(body).css('background-color', 'blue');` which should be `$("body").css('background-color', 'blue');`

Comment: Add an href to `<li><a class="soege-knap mob-nav"></a></li>` and `<li><a class="menu-knap mob-nav" ></a></li>`, pass the even and do event.preventDefault() in the click

Comment: @mplungjan Sorry - added the html now.

Comment: @mplungjan I'll try your suggestion - if I can figure it out

Comment: Weird though. The serach-button (magnifying glass) works fine when toggling the search field without the href

Added the event.preventDefault() but the div still won't show on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry - there is no cure for idiocy.

The div never loaded on the device as I had an php if statement asking it not to include the menu in case if it detected an smartphone.

Ever so sorry!

Comment: No problem - if you delete your answer you can delete your question.

Comment: Will do. Though the event.preventDefault(); don't seem to have any effect. Do you have an idea?

`$fagomraadeknap = $('a#indexbtn');
    $fagomraadeknap.click(function() {
  $('#emneoversigt').toggle();
  event.preventDefault();
 });
 
 $fagomraadeknap.stop()
   event.preventDefault();`

Comment: If I put the functionality on a li instead of an anchor it works. But shoudln't it be possible to dsiable the anchor through preventDefault?

Comment: You only need to prevent on a link: `$someLink.on("click",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ...`